# What is the conceptual difference between the marginal variance and the range in the Matérn covariance?

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance, gaussian-process

The Matérn covariance kernel is given by:

$$
C_\nu(d) = \sigma^2 \frac{2^{1-\nu}}{\Gamma(\nu)}\left(\sqrt{2\nu}\frac{d}{p}\right)^\nu K_\nu\left(\sqrt{2\nu}\frac{d}{p}\right)
$$

My question is, what does $\sigma$ (the "marginal variance"?) mean in contrast to the range $p$? The if $\nu$ goes to infinity then you obtain the square exponential covariance kernel:

$$\sigma^2 \exp\left(-\frac{d^2}{2p^2}\right)
$$

So I guess what I'm asking is - what kind of effects does varying $\sigma$ have on the processes implied by these covariance kernels? And should the kernels be normalized functions -- in the case of the SE kernel, we'd have $\sigma^2 = 1/\sqrt{4\pi p^2}$.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by a "normalized" covariance?

Comment: @whuber I tried to clarify the question a bit.

Comment: Your use of "normalized" seems to be based on confusing two completely different uses of the same expression.  The "normalized function" you refer to at the end is used to make the integral of the expression equal to $1$, which is important when the Gaussian is used as a *probability density function.* Covariance functions are *entirely different things* with completely different defining properties. This suggests that a quick review of how you intend to use your "covariance kernel" would likely reveal the answer to your question about the role of $\sigma^2$.

Comment: @whuber this is in the context of a Gaussian process--I'm just trying to understand the role of the marginal variance, which is given by the covariance function evaluated at zero.

Comment: @cgreen where did you find this definition? The marginal variance of a GP usually refers to variance after you 'marginalise' (integrate) over the input space. For example when someone says they are marginalising over the hyper paramenters using Bayesian Quadrature what they really mean is that they are using a GP on the negative log likelihood of the hyper parameter space and then integrating over all the hyperparameters.